# select same column from many table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

how  i can get a result like this with sql and php?

```
table 1 name = "T1"
column = "ip"
rows = "ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4"
```

,

```
table 2 name = "T2"
column = "ip"
rows = "ip5,ip6,ip7,ip8"
```

,

```
table 3 name = "T3"
column = "ip"
rows = "ip9,ip10"
```

columns name in all table is same

and all tables is in a same database

i want get this output from these three tables:

```
"T1" => "ip1,ip2,ip3,ip4",
"T2" => "ip5,ip6,ip7,ip8",
"T3" => "ip9,ip10"
```

i can do this with several query but i want do this with just one query!

please help

Comment: Try to look for UNION

Comment: @sajjadrast . . . I am confused on what you really want.  SQL tables have rows and columns.  What rows and columns do you want in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If columns names and count are matching you can do union or union all like this

```
SELECT "Table1" as TableName, column1, column2, column3
FROM Table1 
UNION
SELECT "Table2" as TableName, column1, column2, column3
FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT "Table3" as TableName, column1, column2, column3
FROM Table3
```

And The you need to have some logic in your PHP code to do group the rows by first column ie. Table Name>

I hope this helps.